# Security and Policy Injection Application Block

Tags: security, policy-injection

I have a mixed UI (Win App, WPF App, and soon an ASP.NET MVC App) setup, so far I'm using Client Application Services for security.  I know how to programmatically get a user authenticated and doing so is working beautifully.  However...

I want to implement some cross cutting that basically checks to see if the user is authenticated all the time.  Since everything will be accessing web services I want to enable this as a standard execution for pretty much everything the UI does.  So far I'm thinking the PIAB - Policy Injection Application Block - will serve that function.  What I'm wondering is two things;

1 Will the PIAB cover that needed functionality?  Verifying authentication at every practical step if used against the UI?

...and...

2 Are there alternatives out there besides the PIAB?  I'm curious to do a comparison of aspect oriented policy injection frameworks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really familiar with Client Application Services but from my experience, most AOP frameworks wrap interfaces in order to implement the cross-cutting functionality. If CAS uses interfaces, you could probably just wrap them with what ever functionality you require.

Alternative AOP frameworks:

- [Spring.NET](http://www.springframework.net/)
- [Castle Dynamic Proxy](http://www.castleproject.org/dynamicproxy/index.html)

Spring.NET and Dynamic proxy seem to work in much the same way and have much the same performance in my Hello World type tests (about half-way between direct calls and invoking through reflection). PIAB is significantly slower than both these frameworks and I found bit more verbose. It does have the ability to be configurable via xml and I'm not sure if that's a good thing or not. Not sure if the other frameworks provide that. It does of course have the MS stamp of approval though :P.

Comment: Well, just because it has a MS stamp of approval definitely doesn't mean it is the best.  :)  Thx for the answer!

Comment: Indeed. But judging by where I've worked in the past, it definitely matters to some people.